# Parse is undefined in Node JS Controller

Tags: node.js, express, parse-platform

I am trying to build a Node JS + Express web application using Parse.com.  I have this in my server js:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    Parse = require('parse').Parse;
    projects = require('./controllers/projects');

// Parse fun
Parse.initialize('MY_APP_ID_HERE', 'MY_JS_KEY');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.get('/projects',projects.index);
app.get('/projects/new',projects.new);

app.listen(9000);
```

Now in my projects controller:

```
module.exports.create = function(req,res){
    var projectObject = Parse.Object.extend("ProjectObject");
    var project = new projectObject();
    project.save(req.body).then(function(object) {
        res.redirect('/projects');
    });
};

module.exports.index = function(req,res){
    var projectObject = Parse.Object.extend("ProjectObject");
    var query = new Parse.Query(projectObject);
    query.limit(100);
    query.first({
        success: function(projects) {
            // Successfully retrieved the projects.
            res.json(projects);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        }
    });
};
```

This is the error I get:

ReferenceError: Parse is not defined
   at module.exports.create ([REST_OF_PATH_REMOVED]/app/controllers/projects.js:5:22)
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] ([REST_OF_PATH_REMOVED]/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
   at next ([REST_OF_PATH_REMOVED]/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
   at Route.dispatch ([REST_OF_PATH_REMOVED]/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] ([REST_OF_PATH_REMOVED]/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
   at [REST_OF_PATH_REMOVED]/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:277:22
   at Function.process_params ([REST_OF_PATH_REMOVED]/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
   at next ([REST_OF_PATH_REMOVED]/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
   at [REST_OF_PATH_REMOVED]/app/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:121:5
   at done ([REST_OF_PATH_REMOVED]/app/node_modules/body-parser/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:233:14)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer would be to move

```
var Parse = require('parse').Parse;
```

and

```
Parse.initialize('MY_APP_ID_HERE', 'MY_JS_KEY');
```

to your projects controller. They aren't necessary in your server.js file based on the code posted.

Comment: Unfortunately, it still says "Parse is undefined" and complains about the initialize line when added it to the top of the projects controller.

Comment: Have you installed the parse module with 'npm install parse'?

Comment: Yes I have installed parse.  I included it as a dependency in packages.json.  I just ran it "npm install parse" just in case and it is still undefined.

Comment: If I move it to the controller, does that mean for every controller I have declare it again?

Comment: How do I declare it in server.js and use it in multiple controllers?

Comment: So I ended up adding the require and init of Parse to the controller.  I'll have to add it to each controller to make my project work with Parse.  I was hoping I could find a way to add it in one place without a global variable, but it seems it might not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Parse is out of the fn's scope. You could either bring the declaration to your controller as recommended before or (although not a good practice) make Parse a global (just be careful by not overwriting the variable in other parts of your app)

app.js

```
...

global.Parse = require('parse').Parse;

...
```

controller.js

```
...

new Parse.query ...

...
```

Comment: Would I have to include declaration for every controller I create? This doesn't seem right. I also prefer not to make it a global variable.

Comment: If you make it global you won't need to declare it anywhere else, it will be an omnipresent variable (just like `window` on the browser)

Comment: Making it global it's surely not a good practice and if you don't like then you need to declare it on every controller, just make sure you declare it within range of the function's scope

ie:
`var Parse = ...`
`module.exports.create ...`